# Unknown "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="connectedDevices">
                     <script>

                      if (req.user.pebble.watch_token == String) {
                        <i class="fa fa-check"> Pebble </i>
                      } else{
                        <i class="fa fa-warning">No Pebble connected</i>
                      };

                     </script>


                  </div>
```

Using local strategy and Pebble kit to verify if a user has a pebble connected. All the AUTH is working, just wondering why nothing is showing up now.

Comment: What makes you think you can dump HTML in the middle of a piece of JavaScript like that?

Comment: Im using EJS. So it would look like:

Comment: <div class="tab-pane active" id="connectedDevices">
                         <script>
                          
                          if (req.user.pebble.watch_token == String) {
                            <i class="fa fa-check"> "Pebble" </i>
                          } else{
                            <i class="fa fa-warning">"No Pebble connected"</i>
                          };

                         </script>

                         
                      </div>

Comment: The [EJS homepage](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) doesn't suggest you can do that. It expects JavaScript inside HTML but marked with specific tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because `<` isn't allowed where you are putting it. You have a `<` because you have placed some HTML in the middle of your JavaScript.

You say, in the comments, that you are using EJS, but if you were using the syntax shown on the [homepage](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) then your template would look like this:

```
<% if (req.user.pebble.watch_token == String) { %>
    <i class="fa fa-check"> Pebble </i>
<% } else { %>
    <i class="fa fa-warning">No Pebble connected</i>
<% } %>
```

and would be in a `.ejs` template file loaded with:

```
var html = new EJS({url: 'example.ejs'}).render(data);
```

You would then have the HTML in a variable that you could use with `innerHTML` on an element.

Comment: <div class="tab-content">
                      <div class="tab-pane active" id="connectedDevices">
                         <script>
                          
                         <% if (req.user.pebble.watch_token == String) { %>
                            <i class="fa fa-check"> Pebble </i>
                        <% } else { %>
                            <i class="fa fa-warning">No Pebble connected</i>
                        <% } %>

                         </script>

                         
                      </div>

Comment: You should not have a script element in your .ejs template.

Comment: Ok, but the page is now crashing due to a reference error. I'm guessing its the test condition

Comment: It should tell you what variable is causing the reference error.

Comment: Its the test condition.

Answer (score -2):

You need to be inside of a script tag (i.e. ) in order to do what you're doing.  It is called In-Line Javascript and is very useful.

Comment: If it wasn't in a script element, it wouldn't be causing the browser to display a script error.

Comment: I am using the <script></script> tags, I figured people would realize

Comment: No, it actually wouldn't.  It would continue to throw syntactical errors.

Comment: @user1789573 — No, it would treat the JS as text and the HTML as HTML (instead of treating the JS as JS and the HTML as an error)

Comment: But, you forget it is the difference between being INSIDE a tag, and OUTSIDE a tag.  If it's OUTSIDE a tag then it will just be displayed as text.  If it's INSIDE a tag then it throws an error. But, an easy way to end the argument is to have the OP just post the ENTIRE code snippet.

Comment: @user1789573 — Nobody forgot that. That is, in fact, what I said in my last comment. We know that the OP put it in a script element because (a) we know it throws an error and (b) they said they did.

Comment: It actually does't say <script> anywhere in it.  Can you point it out to me where he said <script> anywhere?